# How to show and addtobackstack hidden fragment in android

Tags: android, fragment

I am working in a application where single activity and using multiple fragments,I will describe my problem I have suppose 4 fragments A,B,C,D first I am showing A and after that I am adding B,C, fragments in backstack,next i am showing B fragment from C and added to backstack,here problem is i want to resume B fragment and it should delete from backstack fragments,it is not working please help me.

Code:

```
XFragment xfragment = new XFragment();
Fragment fragment = Utils.getInstance().findExistFragment(_activity);
if (fragment == null) {
    showFragment(xfragment, true, "xfragment", true, false);
} else {
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(fragment).commit();
    showFragment(xFragment, true, "xfragment", true, false);
}
```

Comment: why don't you give a name to the transaction using fragmentTransactionInstance.addToBackStack("name of transaction")  and pop to it when you want to resume it ?

Comment: how to pop specific fragment from backstack entries

Comment: getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack("name of transaction", FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);

Comment: i am trying to remove C fragment but it is removing B,C

Comment: Then pop up only one transaction.i mean when you are trying to show b fragment, you would give transaction a name.right?pop till that transaction.i hope that would help .

Comment: i have suppose A B C fragments in backstack,I am opening B fragment from C,then statck should be A C B